# Django internationalisation and digits behaviour

Tags: html, django, django-views, internationalization

I have a website in English, Spanish, German and French. One of the tables has a meter bar like:

[image: Bar example]

```
<meter value="{{fav.value}}" min="0" max="10"></meter>
```

I found the meter bar only works in the English version, particularly, the meter goes from 0 to 10 with 2 decimals accuracy.

If I override the value in `view.py` with an integer value (e.g. `fav.value = 2`), it works in all languages. If I override the value with a float (e.g. `fav.value = 2.5`), **it would only show the green meter fill in the English version**.

Anyone has any idea what why this may be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have {% load l10n %} in your template. Django localizes the value for every locale. You can disable localization for that specific value.

```
<meter value="{{fav.value|unlocalize}}" min="0" max="10"></meter>
```

[Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/formatting/#template-filters)

Comment: Spot on! I only had `{% load i18n %}` in my template. Funny enough, I had to add `{% load l10n %}` to be able to use `unlocalize` even if it seems `load i18n` already localises values. Thanks so much for your help!